# jquery ajax call with headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to login at tinder using ajax call as per this documentations :

https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467

here, there is table for : **Request headers**

and link for login is this : `> curl -X POST https://api.gotinder.com/auth --data '{"facebook_token": fb_token, "facebook_id": fb_user_id}`'

my only wish here is to login successsfully using this method :

this is what i have tried :-

```
$("#btnSend").click(function () {
                var dataUrl = "https://api.gotinder.com/auth";
                var fbtoken = "[i wrote correct fb token here]";
                var fbId = "[i wrote correct fb id here]";
                var datavalue = '{"facebook_token": "' + fbtoken + '", "facebook_id": "' + fbId + '"}';
                jQuery.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    beforeSend: function (request) {
                        //request.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token",)
                        request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5");
                        request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
                        request.setRequestHeader("UserAgent", "Tinder/3.0.2 (iPhone; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)");
                        request.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                    },
                    headers: {"UserAgent": "Tinder/3.0.2 (iPhone; iOS 7.1; Scale/2.00)"},
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: datavalue,
                    url: dataUrl,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.dir(data);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {

                    }
                });
            });
```

would you please help to set the correct header in request?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'x-my-custom-header': 'some value' }
});

// Sends your custom header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar' });

// Overwrites the default header with a new header
$.ajax({ url: 'foo/bar', headers: { 'x-some-other-header': 'some value' } });
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of how this relates to the question.